Valve Steam local file transfer inconsistent
When transferring files over Steams local transfer feature, the speed is inconsistent and often drops to zero after about two minutes, just to pick up again, go back to full speeds for another 10 seconds, before crashing to zero once more.
After this happens four to five times, it goes to zero one last time and stays there.
After stopping the transfer and waiting for a minute or two, I can restart it and the same will happen again.
My network consists out of two high-end desktop computers connected by a gigabit network switch and Cat6 cables. Both computers have 2.5GBit network adapters.
There are also an openWRT router, a Pi-Hole on an RPi 4 CM and a NAS connected to the switch.
Both PCs are running the latest Windows 11 Pro.
I researched the issue on the internet and have found nothing similar so far.
Is this a Steam issue or might this be my network? What would be helpful troubleshooting steps?

It may simply be the buffer on the destination disk drive filling up, then taking a while to empty to the point where it will accept more data. Does the local transfer feature offer a rate-limiting option?

@AndrewMorton I'll check that out. I assume Steam showing drive transfer rate being at 0 doesn't mean the drive isn't unloading its buffer internally, right? I don't think Steam would pick that up / the drive wouldn't report that?

Can you use Task Manager to look at the performance of the disk drives at each end of the transfer? I missed the bit where you wrote "goes to zero one last time and stays there" which isn't so hopeful, but if the drive still shows activity while Steam says zero then it should just be a case of waiting longer. Also, you could look at network activity and see if anything strange happens with that. What type/model of drives are you transferring between?

@AndrewMorton I'll add that to my question when I'm back home from work. I already checked TM before and it shows zero drive and/or network activity, aka. it corresponds to what Steam is showing aswell. That's why I'm so lost.

Do you have any games that use much smaller amounts of disk space to test it with? There might be some free games of a few hundreds of MB if you haven't. (B) Do the computers have 1GBE ports that could be used instead, seeing as the Ethernet bottleneck is the 1GBE switch? Just to investigate.

And of course any replies to "What would be helpful troubleshooting steps?" should have included "What happens if you simply copy-and-paste the relevant directory from one computer to the other" - which would confirm or refute Steam's part in the problem.
